# firefox extension / javascript - how to access dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon

I am building a Firefox extension to modify web page content.

It is a simple javascript that finds a HTML element and modifies it.
The script is executed when button on toolbar is pressed.

I want to access an element with `id="precont"` but the content on web page is created dynamically (it doesn't show up when right click -> "View Page Source").

This returns `null` (after waiting page to load and executing the script):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("precont");
```

How to gain access to it with javascript?

Comment: Is the dynamic content located in some div with some id or class?

Comment: I can't really tell. The "View Source Code" and what i see in FF inspector are completely different.
The page is: http://www.playok.com/en/chess/
You can log in
user: potatodev
pw:   devdevdev

Comment: "The script is executed when button on toolbar is pressed." is the element you are looking for present in the inspector at that point of time?

Comment: Yes, just checked. I can see it with inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   var elem = document.getElementById("precont");
```

returned `null` because web pages `document` object wasn't directly available in the extension (chrome/button.js)

I gained access via the current window:

```
  var precontElem = window.content.document.getElementById("precont");
```

Comment: Yeah, in XUL overlay add-ons, the overlay script get a `document` but it is not the web content. Instead `document` is the top-level browser window itself aka `browser.xul`. You already figured out that `content.` gives (a shortcut) access to the web content `document` of the currently active tab (please note that this might break once e10s lands)